# insert column - outside group- right option disable in ssrs 10

Tags: reporting-services

I need to add column outside group- right. but it is disabled in ssrs 2010. What to do now?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not insert column outside Group-Right because you are trying to insert just after the column which is not the part of column grouping.
A column which comes under row grouping, you can not insert column outside group-right.